# How to get subdomain inside RouteServiceProvider map() method while phpunit testing?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Is there a way to get the subdomain while running phpunit test in Laravel?

And more specific in this method:

app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();
    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    // inside here get subdomain while running a phpunit test??
```

So if I make some dummy test like this:

```
/** @test */
public function user_can_see_welcome_page()
{
    $response = $this->call('GET', 'https://subdomain.domain.com');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

I want to get the `subdomain` inside that map() method of RouteServiceProvider

Comment: Could you explain why you need this? There might be a better solution, but this will give you the subdomain: `explode('.', request()->server('HTTP_HOST'))[0]`

Comment: I made dd(request()->server('HTTP_HOST')) and only the main domain is there when running phpunit, but subdomain is there when opening through web browser!
I need this to map the routes dependable on subdomain

Comment: Tried now a few different approaches but nothing helps because the route mapping gets done BEFORE the test even gets triggered... seems like a dead end to me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the domain you can add it to the `phpunit.xml` to set it globally:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_URL" value="https://subdomain.domain.com"/>
</php>
```

But discussing your problem in the comments, this is the actual solution to your problem:

**Multiple route files:**

You could split each subdomain in its own map method and route file and register them in your `RouteServiceProvider`.

for each subdomain:

```
protected function mapSubDomainRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'domain' => 'subdomain.domain.com',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function () {
        require base_path('routes/subdomain.domain.php');
    });
}
```

**Single route file:**

Or if you have everything inside one route file you can wrap the routes inside a group:

```
Route::group(['domain' => ['subdomain.domain.com']], function () {
    // domain specific routes
});
```

Comment: Yes that is why we set the environment variable before the framework gets booted for the test

Comment: It doesn't change the env variable

Comment: Yes, adding that line indeed changes it but I have 3 subdomains and I need to map ONLY the routes for that subdomain which is currently triggered on this exact request... Is this even possible?

Comment: One more interesting thing: When you run phpunit test the entry point is not `public/index.php` how come???

Comment: What I don't quite understand is why you even need that variable inside the map method, you can let laravel register all routes and then add the `domain` param e.g. `'domain' => 'subdomain.domain.com'` to the route group to only apply the routes to certain domains.

Comment: @lewis4u I edited my answer, could you take a look at it.